# Как применить state на весь групповой чат aiogram?

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlite, aiogram

Условно, есть групповой чат, и если юзер пишет команду /menu, то бот пишет "Введите цену", причем, это должно работать не только на него, но и на весь чат (если напишет другой человек помимо него, оно также должно работать).

Я пытался сделать, не получилось.